# PHPlot doesn't show an image

Tags: php, joomla, graph, phplot

I just downloaded PHPlot and included it into a php file. I tried to get an example work, but there are only some signs not a graph.

I'm Using XAMPP and Joomla.

This shows me:

[image]

I need GD enabled, just a screenshot of my GD settings:

[image: http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3382/jv3omrny_jpg.htm]

Did I do anything wrong?

---

I tried to place the file outside of joomla and placed it to xampp - it works. But I need that graph inside my joomla installation.

Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
require '/libraries/phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php';
$data = array(
        array('', 1800,   5), array('', 1810,   7), array('', 1820,  10),
        array('', 1830,  13), array('', 1840,  17), array('', 1850,  23),
        array('', 1860,  31), array('', 1870,  39), array('', 1880,  50),
        array('', 1890,  63), array('', 1900,  76), array('', 1910,  92),
        array('', 1920, 106), array('', 1930, 123), array('', 1940, 132),
        array('', 1950, 151), array('', 1960, 179), array('', 1970, 203),
        array('', 1980, 227), array('', 1990, 249), array('', 2000, 281),
);

$plot = new PHPlot(800, 600);
$plot->SetImageBorderType('plain');

$plot->SetPlotType('lines');
$plot->SetDataType('data-data');
$plot->SetDataValues($data);

# Main plot title:
$plot->SetTitle('US Population, in millions');

# Make sure Y axis starts at 0:
$plot->SetPlotAreaWorld(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
$plot->DrawGraph();
// phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: I believe you need to use `header( "Content-type: image/png" );` in there if using a PNG. Replace `png` with `jpg` or `jpeg` if output as JPG and `gif` if a GIF. Then echo your output variable.

Comment: I added that line into my code, but it doesnt change anything. My output variable? Thought "DrawGraph()" should output the graph, doenst it?
I tried to do this example: http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/examples.html

Comment: The placement of the header will be crucial. You cannot place it just "anywhere". I'm not sure where to put it, but you need it in there. You will have to continue reading on their site.

Comment: Where did you put the header line, can you update your code please?

Comment: @monti And then again it could be a path problem with your `phplot.php` - Try running the whole thing from within the same folder and see.

Comment: @monti Actually it IS a path problem. I downloaded the code and got an error. Place your example files and `data_table.php` inside the same folder as `phplot.php` and it will work. No need for `header`. Open all files and you will see `require_once 'phplot.php'; 
require_once 'data_table.php';` those need to be inside the same folder as `phplot.php` etc. including `data_table.example3.php`

Comment: This works if its outside of joomla, I tried this inside joomla - no differents. I still get that view of signs

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using PHPlot with AJAX. The solution is to create a new file with only the graph code, eg createGraph.php. So I call this file in my img tag like this: `echo '<img src = "createGraph.php" />'`;

I can also pass via GET parameters to customize the chart, as follows:
`echo '<img src = "createGraph.php?title=My_Graph&val1=1&val2=2" />';` and createGraph.php, get through GET the dynamic information of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the headers before your serve up the image, The actual data in the screenshot looks like an image file:
put this in before your last line.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

Comment: Oh, beaten to it by Fred !!

Comment: LOL! not a problem. But it seems like it's not working for the OP.

Comment: mh, Im actually new to this.I added that line just before "DrawGraph()". But it doesnt help, its the same output as it was before

Comment: ok, try adding this in too:
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="graph.png"');`

just as a test to see if you can open the image on your computer.

Comment: I cant open the file, but its 23KB "big".

Comment: also try adding this in to see if there are any errors, but you will want to remove this as it will muck things up with your headers:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: @Joeme It's not `header` after all, it's a file path problem.

Comment: ok, also have you checked your folder permissions, phplot require writable cache folder? I think that displaying errors could give you the clue.

Comment: mh, added both lines, but I dont know where the browser should write that error. 

uff, Im working with windows and admin - so xampp should have full access

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the Header.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/gif');

require '/../../../../../../libraries/phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php';

$data = array(
    array('', 1800,   5), array('', 1810,   7), array('', 1820,  10),
    array('', 1830,  13), array('', 1840,  17), array('', 1850,  23),
    array('', 1860,  31), array('', 1870,  39), array('', 1880,  50),
    array('', 1890,  63), array('', 1900,  76), array('', 1910,  92),
    array('', 1920, 106), array('', 1930, 123), array('', 1940, 132),
    array('', 1950, 151), array('', 1960, 179), array('', 1970, 203),
    array('', 1980, 227), array('', 1990, 249), array('', 2000, 281),
);

$plot = new PHPlot(800, 600);
$plot->SetImageBorderType('plain');

$plot->SetPlotType('lines');
$plot->SetDataType('data-data');
$plot->SetDataValues($data);

# Main plot title:
$plot->SetTitle('US Population, in millions');

# Make sure Y axis starts at 0:
$plot->SetPlotAreaWorld(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

$plot->DrawGraph();

?>
```

WARNING: Be aware to set the header only once. Any output before `header` will end in a warning "Header already sent".

For more informations look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: It's not a `header` problem after all, it's a path issue with OP's demo files.

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't noticed the comment. To much comments in a short time.